# find middle elements from an array

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++ how can i find the middle 'n' elements of an array? For example if n=3, and the array is [0,1,5,7,7,8,10,14,20], the middle is [7,7,8].

p.s. in my context, n and the elements of array are odd numbers, so i can find the middle.
Thanks!

Comment: What has your approach been so far?  Show us what you need help with, rather than ask us to do it for you.

Comment: No, i'm working on a digital image processing application. is there any function in C++?

Comment: Is the array always sorted, as in example? If so then just take subarray from the middle. If not then shuffle elements in the example so that it's clear.

Comment: No, you have to write your own function which does that

Comment: Nhf, but I find it a bit hard to believe that somebody who's writing an image processing app can't solve this problem on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quick, not tested but the basic idea...

```
const int n = 5;

// Get middle index
int arrLength = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(int);

int middleIndex = (arrLength - 1) / 2;
// Get sides
int side = (n - 1) / 2;

int count = 0;

int myNewArray[n];

for(int i = middleIndex - side; i <= middleIndex + side; i++){
     myNewArray[count++] = myArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int values[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
const size_t total(sizeof(values) / sizeof(int));
const size_t needed(3);

vector<int> middle(needed);
std::copy(values + ((total - needed) / 2), 
    values + ((total + needed) / 2), middle.begin());
```

Have not checked this with all possible boundary conditions.  With the sample data I get `middle = (3,4,5)`, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have to pick `n` numbers, you know there will be `size - n` unpicked items. As you want to pick numbers in the middle, you want to have as many 'unpicked' number on each side of the array, that is `(size - n) / 2`.

I won't do your homework, but I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the naive algorithm follows:

1. Find the middle, which exists because you specified that the length is odd.
2. Repeatedly pick off one element to the left and one element to the right. You can always do this because you specified that `n` is odd.

You can also make the following observation:

Note that after you've picked the middle, there are `n - 1` elements remaining to pick off. This is an even number and `(n - 1)/2` must come from the left of the middle element and `(n - 1)/2` must come from the right. The middle element has index `(length - 1)/2`. Therefore, the lower index of the first element selected is `(length - 1)/2 - (n - 1)/2` and the upper index of the last element selected is `(length - 1)/2 + (n - 1)/2`. Consequently, the indices needed are `(length - n)/2 - 1` to `(length + n)/2 - 1`.